# multiply 2 elements for each select and tally results

Tags: jquery, function, each

I have multiple selects:

```
 <select name="1a[b]" class="5.00">
     <option value='1' selected >Choice 1</option>
     <option value="2"  >Choice 2</option>
</select>
<select  name="2a[b]" class="2.50">
     <option value='1' >Choice 1</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Choice 2</option>

</select>
```

I would like to get the value multiplied by the class for each select that has a[b] in its name and then add up that value for all the selects. So the desired results for the above would be:

```
(5.00 * 1) + (2.50 * 2) = 10.00
```

I have used this to get a total for an individual select but am unable to do so in an each method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name*='a[b]']").change(function(){
   alert( $(this).val()  * $(this).attr("class") ); 

});
</script>
```

I have barked up every wrong tree all day long.   Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe `.` isn't a valid CSS class name character.

Comment: I can get/use the class value no problem when working with a single select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using data attribute instead of storing values in class ( i think thats more appropriate than using classes for storing values )

```
var selects =  $("select[name*='a[b]']");

 $("select[name*='a[b]']").on('change',function(){
     var total = 0;
     $(selects).each(function(i,current){
           var val = $(current).val();
           var data = $(current).attr('data-val');
           total += val*data;

     });
     alert(total)
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/owyfnuu1/